# Why my DataProcessing\MenuProcessor don't show level-3 and level-4 for my page tree

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I use Bootstrap_package v10 and Typo3 9, the menu processor doesn't show the level-3 and 4 for my pagetree.

I'm using the original templates from bootstrap package, the code is below:

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
10 {
    levels = 5
    special = directory
    special.value = 26969
    expandAll = 1
    includeSpacer = 1
    as = mainnavigation
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10 {
            references.fieldName = nav_icon
            as = icon
            if {
                isTrue.stdWrap.cObject = COA
                isTrue.stdWrap.cObject {
                    10 = TEXT
                    10.value = 1
                    10.if.isTrue = {$page.theme.navigation.icon.enable}
                    20 = TEXT
                    20.value = 1
                    20.if.isTrue = {$page.theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.enable}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the fluid code :

```html
<f:section name="MainNavigation">
    <f:if condition="{menu}">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <f:for each="{menu}" as="item">
                <f:if condition="{item.spacer}">
                    <f:then>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>
                        <li class="nav-item{f:if(condition: item.active, then:' active')}{f:if(condition: item.children, then:' dropdown dropdown-hover')}">
                            <a href="{item.link}" id="nav-item-{item.data.uid}" class="nav-link{f:if(condition: item.children, then:' dropdown-toggle')}"{f:if(condition: item.target, then: ' target="{item.target}"')} title="{item.title}"{f:if(condition: item.children, then:' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"')}>
                                <f:if condition="{theme.navigation.icon.enable} && {item.icon}">
                                    <span class="nav-link-icon">
                                        <f:if condition="{item.icon.0.extension} === svg">
                                            <f:then>
                                                <bk2k:inlineSvg image="{item.icon.0}" width="{theme.navigation.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.icon.height}" />
                                            </f:then>
                                            <f:else>
                                                <f:image image="{item.icon.0}" alt="{item.icon.0.alternative}" title="{item.icon.0.title}" width="{theme.navigation.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.icon.height}" />
                                            </f:else>
                                        </f:if>
                                    </span>
                                </f:if>
                                <span class="nav-link-text">{item.title}<f:if condition="{item.current}"> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></f:if></span>
                            </a>
                            <f:if condition="{item.children}">
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nav-item-{item.data.uid}">
                                    <f:for each="{item.children}" as="child">
                                        <f:if condition="{child.spacer}">
                                            <f:then>
                                                <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                            </f:then>
                                            <f:else>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="{child.link}" class="dropdown-item{f:if(condition: child.active, then:' active')}"{f:if(condition: child.target, then: ' target="{child.target}"')} title="{child.title}">
                                                        <f:if condition="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.enable} && {child.icon}">
                                                            <span class="dropdown-icon">
                                                                <f:if condition="{child.icon.0.extension} === svg">
                                                                    <f:then>
                                                                        <bk2k:inlineSvg image="{child.icon.0}" width="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.height}" />
                                                                    </f:then>
                                                                    <f:else>
                                                                        <f:image image="{child.icon.0}" alt="{child.icon.0.alternative}" title="{child.icon.0.title}" width="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.height}" />
                                                                    </f:else>
                                                                </f:if>
                                                            </span>
                                                        </f:if>
                                                        <span class="dropdown-text">{child.title}<f:if condition="{child.current}"> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></f:if></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </f:else>
                                        </f:if>
                                    </f:for>
                                </ul>
                            </f:if>
                        </li>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </f:for>
        </ul>
    </f:if>
</f:section>
```

The fluid is calling a page child but i don't know if it is recursive or not so it can showa all levels, what am I missing there, it seems like i'm the first one that having this issue ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should verify if the data is available for more than the first two levels:
insert a `<f:debug title="mainnavigation">{mainnavigation}</f:debug>` in your template.

Then inspect your templates whether they are ready to display more than two levels.
I can imagine your templates show the first level, for second level a partial is called, but that partial does not call itself if necessary.
Except if you need some level specific markup (e.g. `'class="level1"`) you can build up menus by stacking the levels inside each other (giving stacked `ul`s). So you either have a recursive call with stacked menus of the same markup or you define a partial for each level with individual markup (or you define a variable which contains the current level and call the partial recursive).

---

it's even worse: both levels are written out in the same template file, no partial (or section) is used.

I would change it to:
(I stayed with one file and instead of an additional partials I call a section, which can be in the same file)

```
<f:section name="MainNavigation">
    <f:if condition="{menu}">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <f:for each="{menu}" as="item">
                <f:render section="subLevel" arguments="{item:item}" />
            </f:for>
        </ul>
    </f:if>
</f:section>

<f:section name="subLevel">
    <f:if condition="{item.spacer}">
         <f:then>
             <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
         </f:then>
         <f:else>
             <li class="nav-item{f:if(condition: item.active, then:' active')}{f:if(condition: item.children, then:' dropdown dropdown-hover')}">
                 <a href="{item.link}" id="nav-item-{item.data.uid}" class="nav-link{f:if(condition: item.children, then:' dropdown-toggle')}"{f:if(condition: item.target, then: ' target="{item.target}"')} title="{item.title}"{f:if(condition: item.children, then:' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"')}>
                 <f:if condition="{theme.navigation.icon.enable} && {item.icon}">
                      <span class="nav-link-icon">
                          <f:if condition="{item.icon.0.extension} === svg">
                              <f:then>
                                  <bk2k:inlineSvg image="{item.icon.0}" width="{theme.navigation.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.icon.height}" />
                              </f:then>
                              <f:else>
                                  <f:image image="{item.icon.0}" alt="{item.icon.0.alternative}" title="{item.icon.0.title}" width="{theme.navigation.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.icon.height}" />
                              </f:else>
                          </f:if>
                      </span>
                  </f:if>
                  <span class="nav-link-text">{item.title}<f:if condition="{item.current}"> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></f:if></span>
                 </a>
                 <f:if condition="{item.children}">
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="nav-item-{item.data.uid}"> 
                         <f:for each="{item.children}" as="child">
                             <f:render section="subLevel" arguments="{item:child}" />
                         </for>
                     </ul>
                </f:if>
            </li>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:section>
```

**Notice** the changed markup for spacer in the first level!
Further changes might occur as I have not compared the code but concentrated on building up clean markup.

---

**Increasing a 'parameter' for the recursion.**

for an increasing value (`level1`, `level2`, `level3`...) you need a viewhelper in TYPO3 prior version 9:
this viewhelper can be realised in typoscript:

```
lib.math = TEXT
lib.math {
  current = 1
  prioriCalc = 1
}
```

then you can change the initial call to the `SubLevel` section to:

```
<f:render section="subLevel" arguments="{item:item,level:1}" />
```

Now you have a fluid variable `level` with the value `1`.

the recursive call must be changed to:

```
<f:render section="subLevel" arguments="{item:child,level:{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.math', data:'{level}+1')}}" />
```

for increasing values `2`, `3`, `4` ...

Comment: i have added the fluid code for the menu to the first message, i don't really know if it is recursive call, how can i debug this to know ?

Comment: I enhanced my answer with a one file solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this saved my life.

Comment: Can i improve your code to add a level class e.g., <ul class="level-1"> ... <ul class="level-2"> ?

Comment: then you need an additional parameter which must be increased with each recursive call. Calculation is build in in fluid since TYPO3 9, with earlier versions you need a viewhelper to calculate the next level (see edited answer)

Comment: Oh that's great, i really like this version 9, thanks for the answer improve.

Comment: in TYPO3 v9 upwards you simply use `{f:variable(name: 'level', value: '{level + 1}')}
    <f:for each="{item.children}" as="child">
     <f:render section="subLevel" arguments="{item:child,level:level}" />
    </f:for>`

Answer (score 1):

By default, `MenuProcessor` does not expand all levels. It will only show the branch you're on up to the level below the level you are on. If you want to show all levels for all branches you have to add `expandAll = 1` to your configuration:

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
10 {
  levels = 5
  expandAll = 1
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, now, i added expandAll = 1, but this didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: In that case you should try @BerndWilkeπφ 's suggestion to debug the variable and check your template.

Answer (score 0):

Your Fluid template shows only 2 levels. By default in the Bootstrap package, you have a 2-level menu.
If you want to have more, you need to adjust the template to render more levels.
Here is the rendering of level 2 in your template:

```
<f:for each="{item.children}" as="child">
    <f:render section="subLevel" arguments="{item:child}" />
</f:for>
```

If you want to render level 3, you need to go to the section `subLevel` and check if there are children of every `item` you set in `arguments`.
Example:

```
<f:if condition="{item.children}">
    <ul>
        <f:for each="{item.children}" as="level3Item">
             ...
        </f:for>
    </ul>
</f:if>
```

You should have some CSS for 5 levels of course. :)

I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

For levels beyond 2, I find it much easier to build in typoscript in your setup.typoscript.

```
lib.textmenu {

# We define the first level as text menu.
 1 = TMENU

 # The first level of this menu. 0 is rootline. -1 is 1 level up from rootline. 1 is 1 level down from rootline
entryLevel = 0

# UID's to exclude from the menu.  Change this for each subsite, but will require a new template on each subsite.
excludeUidList = 21

 # Turn spacers on, I use them to do sections of my menu.
 1.SPC = 1
 1.SPC.allWrap = <li class="a nav-item dropdown text-light bg-secondary SPC">|</li>

# Expand the whole menu - ie a sitemap
1.expAll = 1

# We define the normal state ("NO").
1.NO = 1
1.NO.wrap = <li class="nav-item NO">|</li>
1.NO.linkWrap = <li class="nav-item NO">|</li>
1.NO.ATagParams = class="nav-item dropdown NO"

# We define the active state ("ACT").
1.ACT = 1
1.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nav-item active ACT">|</li>

# Get level 2 to get the format from level 1
2 <.1

# Do some customization for level 2
2.CUR = 1
2.CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="nav-item dropdown active level2CUR">|</li>
2.CUR.ATagParams = class="active text-white"

# Make Levels 3 to 6 the same as level 1. I'll leave it to you to study all the typoscript wrapping.
3 < .1
4 < .1
5 < .1
6 < .1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Mohamed Masmoudi!

I am a newbie with TYPO3. I was asking myself the same question like you.
After a lot of research I found a solution which works for me (TYPO3 v10.4.12 and bootstrap-package) at least in **desktop view mode**.
But I don't understand what exactly is happening in **mobile view**. Maybe someone can give me a hint???
The sublevel is existing in source-code but is not showing up in mobile view.

*First step* was to modify the MenuProcessor in setup.typoscript

```
    ##########################
    ### DATA PREPROCESSING ###
    ##########################
    dataProcessing {
        1 = BK2K\BootstrapPackage\DataProcessing\ConstantsProcessor
        1 {
            as = theme
            key = page.theme
        }
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            #modify these lines
            levels = 5
            expandAll = 1
            includeSpacer = 1
            as = mainnavigation
```

*Second step* modify the
/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/Navigation/Main.html
by adding the following lines to the fluid-template directly after the

```
<a href="{child.link}" class="dropdown-item{f:if(condition: child.active, then:' active')}"{f:if(condition: child.target, then: ' target="{child.target}"')} title="{child.title}">
...
</a>
```

here it comes:

```
<!-- 3rd Level -->                                                  
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown2-menu">
                                                  <f:for each="{child.children}" as="child2">
                                                     <li>
                                                        <a href="{child2.link}" class="dropdown-item{f:if(condition: child2.active, then:' active')}"{f:if(condition: child2.target, then: ' target="{child2.target}"')} title="{child2.title}">
                                                            <f:if condition="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.enable} && {child.icon}">
                                                                <span class="dropdown-icon">
                                                                    <f:if condition="{child.icon.0.extension} === svg">
                                                                        <f:then>
                                                                            <bk2k:inlineSvg image="{child.icon.0}" width="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.height}" />
                                                                        </f:then>
                                                                        <f:else>
                                                                             <f:image additionalAttributes="{loading: 'lazy'}" image="{child.icon.0}" alt="{child.icon.0.alternative}" title="{child.icon.0.title}" width="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.width}" height="{theme.navigation.dropdown.icon.height}" />
                                                                        </f:else>
                                                                    </f:if>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </f:if>
                                                                <span class="dropdown2-text">{child2.title}<f:if condition="{child2.current}"> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></f:if></span>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </li>
                                                  
                                                  </f:for>
                                                </ul>
<!-- End of 3rd Level -->
```

As you see I added a child2. You can add further sublevels like child3 etc by adding them after the particular `<a>...</a>`-tag

Don't forget to close all the open tags.

To separate the new sublevels by CSS I added a dropdown2-menu-Class to the  tag.
Now you can add for example a `.dropdown2-menu {margin-left: 50px}` to your CSS.

Of course it is better not to touch the Bootstrap-Package. Instead use your own sitepackage. You can build one @ https://sitepackagebuilder.com/

All of this is only to remember myself, what I was doing and maybe to help others... :-)